# .NET Manipulating and Display an SVG on a WinForm

Tags: .net, vb.net, svg

I would like to display an SVG File on a WinForm application.

I installed the SVG.NET package and was able to place the SVG on the form all good from that standpoint. The SVG is the image of a race track and I would like to display a circle to indicate a certain percentage a car is on the path. Someone shared some code with me in JavaScript that does basically what I want to do but haven't been able to figure it out using the SVG.NET package.  Below is the sample java script and I put it in JSFiddle with 1 resource of svg.min.js.  This does basically what I want.  Draws the SVG and places a circle on the path at a certain percentage.

```
var draw = SVG().addTo('body').size(2000, 2000)

var daytona = draw.path('M1842.6,250.2c-27.9-59.4-67.1-96.6-88-113.5c-106.9-86.6-233.7-87-317.7-87.2c-7,0-13.6,0-19.9-0.1,c-159.1-1.7-470.5-4.9-629-6.2c-21-0.2-48.3-0.5-77.1-0.8c-78.2-0.9-175.5-2-231.8-1.4c-113.1,1.2-194.8,22.4-265,68.8h0,c-50.8,33.6-90,77.1-116.3,129.2c-25.1,49.5-32,94.4-33.9,116.8c-7.7,91.7,17.2,174,74,244.6c51.7,64.2,119,104.8,166.3,127.6,C368.8,759,468.8,799.5,549.1,832c34.9,14.1,67.9,27.5,93.4,38.2c82.1,34.5,204,80,321.3,80c2.7,0,5.5,0,8.2-0.1,c84.7-1.6,153.2-12.8,215.6-35.4l2.1-0.8c119-43.1,318.1-115.2,418.5-164.7c53.5-26.4,109.8-57.1,159-102.8,c28.2-26.2,51.1-55,68.1-85.5c19.7-35.4,32.1-74.3,36.9-115.6C1880.3,374.9,1870.4,309.3,1842.6,250.2z');

daytona.fill('none').move(20, 20)
daytona.stroke({ color: '#f06', width: 15, linecap: 'round', linejoin: 'round' })

var circle = draw.circle(20)

var length = daytona.length();

var percent = 0.70;
var offset = .71;

percent = (percent + offset) - 1;
console.log("Percent: " + percent);

var p = daytona.pointAt((percent * length));
circle.center(p.x -1, p.y);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For help, you kind of need to ask a question.  What exactly is the problem?  Coverting the javascript to vb.net code?

Comment: Sorry maybe it wasn't clear.  But I would like to do the same functionality in VB or C .NET.  The information is coming from a game.  I get the percentage of the track the car is currently on and I want to draw a red dot representing the car on the the path and be able to update it as it continues.  

I have the SVG images for the path of the race track.  Just looking for a way to draw the image and place a dot at the current percentage of the path.

Comment: Sorry, but to be blunt, repeating the question again doesn't exactly explain anything more.  What aspect of this exactly is the problem?  What is the relevance of the code you've posted in regard to your exact problem?